# How to make square overlay appear with touch?

Tags: ios, camera, uiimage, overlay

The app that I'm currently working on is supposed to overlay a square image. The square image would overlay on preview camera screen wherever the user touches the screen.

I'm having hard time figuring this out. Guidance would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/pARk/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011083) that overlays points of interest on top of the camera view.

They have another [sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190) that overlays a square.